# A vector-output image generator alternative to ImageMagick's "convert" bash command

Tags: bash, vector, imagemagick

I'm doing some txt->image generating using "convert" of ImageMagick. But it outputs only rasterized images, which saved in .eps is a bit useless. Is there any alternative to "convert" so that I can write bash scripts which, by parsing text files, gives me a vector output?

Comment: What kind of content is in your text files? (If you're flexible, you can do things with various LaTeX graphics packages like TikZ or pstricks)

Comment: It is just a list of words on which base a set of images should be generated.

Comment: What kind of vector output? Do you need the actual path from the letters? Is an svg text element enough?

Comment: Incidentally, you could `convert` to eps, then `ps2pdf`, then `pdf2svg`. The result might not be any more pleasant, though.

Comment: My requirements are simple - after reading a line of text (one or two words) create a vector image of that text (no converting to paths, just a text) and save it as an .eps. 

@DavidZaslavsky I thought of using LaTeX, but is it possible to define canvas sizes and adapt text size based on canvas size which will be fixed?

Comment: Yes,you can set the page size and text size in LaTeX. In any case, the size matters very little until you rasterize the image, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer. It's not a one-liner, but still does the job.

First, you have to render the text and measure it's dimensions - use conjure on a template file, i.e.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<image>
   <query-font-metrics text="English (American)" font="Helvetica" pointsize="24" />
   <print output="%[msl:font-metrics.width]x%[msl:font-metrics.height]"/>
</image>
```

If the text is too big decrease if it's too small increase it.

After receiving font size create an SVG file containing invisible rectangle with the dimensions given and text centred in it. Then convert it using Inkscape to .eps

TA-DA